# Кастомный JDBC не загружается в интеграционных тестах Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, тестирование

Я делаю собственный драйвер JDBC, и мне нужно его протестировать (с помощью Spring-boot). Я добавил зависимость (я использую Maven) этого JAR-файла драйвера в другой проект, и он отлично работает в основной программе. Но когда я пытаюсь сделать интеграционные тесты (в модульных всё в порядке), драйвер не загружается, поэтому Spring-Boot не может создать bean-компонент с именем `dataSource`.

Примечание: JDBC использует `service provider mechanism` для загрузки драйверов, поэтому у меня также есть файл `java.sql.Driver` в ресурсах (`src/main/resources/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`).

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы драйвер смог зарегистрироваться во время интеграционных тестов с Spring?

Файлы из ресурсов присутствуют на выходе при сборке, как я и писал выше: при запуске основной программы (и модульных тестов) всё работает нормально, проблемы только при запуске тестов.

Есть ли какие-то особенности работы спринга с драйверами JDBC при интеграционных тестах? Тако ощущение, что не работает service provider.

[Ссылка на проект на гитхабе, там же есть ссылка на проект, в котором пытаюсь запустить интеграционные тесты](https://github.com/V31R/jdbc-mock-driver/tree/check_driver_work)

Код интеграционного теста прост:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationSmokeTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoad(){
        
        assertTrue(true);

    }

}
```

Зависимости:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>HttpDriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

В свойствах я пытался подключать такими способами:

1.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:wm://localhost:8080/sql-mock
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.example.HttpDriver
```

2. jdbc.driverClassName=org.example.HttpDriver
   jdbc.url=jdbc:wm://localhost:8080/sql-mock

Comment: Еще я бы добавил `debug=true` в `application.properties` и посмотрел `CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT` в логе, что автоконфигурация добавила.

Comment: Логи у меня есть, в них я вижу, что автоконфигурация  использует `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` и ему подобное.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA и JDBC же работает, как я понял,  так, что он находит все доступные ему реализации `java.sql.Driver`, а когда пытаемся подключиться к определённому он идёт по всем зарегистрированным драйверам и спрашивает у них подходит url или нет.  Но в интеграционных тестах регистрации кастомного драйвера не происходит как таковой.

Comment: По идее, если используется явное указание класса драйвера в свойствах, то регистрация не нужна, не вижу в ней смысла. Какой полный stacktrace? Я бы от него плясал, поставил бы точку останова в месте, где пытается загрузить драйвер, и смотрел, как spring это делает, почему не находит

Comment: Не, там работает так, что SPI находит файл и загружает класс, который уже статическим методом регистрируется и добавляется  в `private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<DriverInfo> registeredDrivers` у `DriverManager`. У моего же класса при интеграционных тестах со спрингом не вызывается метод регистрации, будто SPI не видит его. Хотя при в основой программе (там спринг есть тоже) и в модульных тестах драйвер успешно регистрирует себя. Если же драйвер не зарегистрировался, то `DriverManager` вернёт null (если нет других подходящих)

Comment: ой, я сейчас увидел, что `No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"`. Пойду проверять, почему ему не нравятся профили. Спасибо вам за помощь.